# Could not find local host metadata file 'host.json'

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I want to use azure-functions-core-tools "func durable delete-task-hub" this command to delete taskhub under a storage account (I have current context's storage's connection string). But when I run this command, it reports:

Could not find local host metadata file 'host.json'
Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json, local.settings.json in project root.

Could I use this command to delete taskhub in azure portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I use this command to delete taskhub in azure portal?

Azure Functions core Tools commands are used to run from your local IDE terminal or command prompt as mentioned in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash).

> Could not find local host metadata file 'host.json' Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json, local.settings.json in project root.

You have to place your task hub name in the `host.json` file as the format specified in [Azure Durable Functions `Host.json` settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp,2x-durable-functions#hostjson-settings).

```
func durable delete-task-hub --task-hub-name TestHubName
```

With this command, you can delete the all storage artifacts including Azure storage tables, queues, and blobs. associated with a particular task hub,

When I run my Azure Durable Function, I came to know the Task Hub Name from the 1st result and passed to the above command, it successfully deleted:

[image]

**Cleanup `taskhubs` Programmatically**:

Through code, you can clean up the `taskhubs` present in a storage account, refer to this [GitHub Ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/448#issuecomment-429086717) for the code given by [cgillum](https://github.com/cgillum).

Comment: So if I don't have the project in local, I cannot use this func cmd to delete taskhubs of a storage account already deployed?

Comment: You can cleanup them using code, given the code reference in the Answer, please check!